# Error while defining mongoose schemas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I am new to mongo and mongoose. I am trying to create 3 collections Users, Articles and Comments. I want the users documents should contain articles that users have saved. The articles object should have users and comments as embedded objects and comments should have embedded user objects.
I want this to be done using the ids of the individual objects so that I can reduce the loading time, but could not find a suitable way to do so using mongoose. Please suggest how should I proceed with the Schema implementation.

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
    profilePicture: String,
    password: String,
    readingList: [articleSchema]
});

var commentsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    content: String,
    votes:{
        up:[UserSchema],
        down:[UserSchema]
    },
    comments:[commentsSchema],
    timestamp:Date.now
});


var articleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    content: String,
    image: String,
    votes:{
        up: [UserSchema],
        down: [UserSchema]
    },
    comments:[commentsSchema],
    timestamp: Date.now
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is failing because `articleSchema` isn't defined when you're using it in the `UserSchema`. Unfortunately, you can reverse the order of defining the schema because they're dependent on each other.

I haven't actually tried this, but based on some quick googling there is a way to create the Schema first and then add the properties.

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema();
var CommentsSchema = new mongoose.Schema();
var ArticleSchema = new mongoose.Schema();

UserSchema.add({
    name: String,
    email: String,
    profilePicture: String,
    password: String,
    readingList: [ArticleSchema]
});

CommentsSchema.add({
    content: String,
    votes:{
        up:[UserSchema],
        down:[UserSchema]
    },
    comments:[CommentsSchema],
    timestamp:Date.now
});

ArticleSchema.add({
    title: String,
    content: String,
    image: String,
    votes:{
        up: [UserSchema],
        down: [UserSchema]
    },
    comments:[CommentsSchema],
    timestamp: Date.now
});
```

Comment: I just used ObjectIds as it'll be easier for me to implement and manage. Thanks for the help anyways!